# Generating DataFrame with combination of columns and sum of grouped values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

So, I have a DataFrame, in which each row represent an event, formed by essentially 4 columns:

```
      happen start_date   end_date  number
0 2015-01-01 2015-01-01 2015-01-03   100.0
1 2015-01-01 2015-01-01 2015-01-01    20.0
2 2015-01-01 2015-01-02 2015-01-02    50.0
3 2015-01-02 2015-01-02 2015-01-02    40.0
4 2015-01-02 2015-01-02 2015-01-03    50.0
```

where `happen` is the date the event took place, `start_date` and `end_date` are the validity of that event, and `number` is just a summable variable.

What I'd like to get is a DataFrame that has for each row the combination of the `happen` date and `validity` date and, contextually, the sum of the `number` column.

What I tried so far is a double for loop on all dates, knowing that `start_date >= happen`:

```
startdate = pd.to_datetime('01/06/2014', format='%d/%m/%Y') # the minimum possible happen
enddate = pd.to_datetime('31/12/2021', format='%d/%m/%Y') # the maximum possible happen (and validity)
```

```
df_day = pd.DataFrame()
for dt1 in pd.date_range(start=startdate, end=enddate):
    for dt2 in pd.date_range(start=dt1, end=enddate):
        num_sum = df[(df['happen'] == dt1)&(df['start_date'] <= dt2)&
                   (df['end_date'] >= dt2)]['number'].sum()
        row = {'happen':dt1,'valid':dt2,'number':num_sum}
        df_day = df_day.append(row,ignore_index = True)
```

and that never came to an end. So I tried other way, I generated the `df` with all date combination first (like 3.8e6 rows), and then tried to fill it with a lambda func (it's crazy, I know, but don't know how to work around it):

```
dt1 = pd.date_range(start=startdate, end=enddate).tolist()
df_day = pd.DataFrame()

for i in dt1:
    dt_acc1 = [i]
    dt2 = pd.date_range(start=i, end=enddate).tolist()
    df_comb = pd.DataFrame(list(product(dt_acc1, dt2)), columns=['happen', 'valid'])
    df_day = df_day.append(df_comb, ignore_index=True)

df_day['number'] = 0
def append_num(happen,valid):
    return df[(df['happen'] == happen)&(df['start_date'] <= valid)&
              (df['end_date'] >= valid)]['number'].sum()

df_day['number'] = df_day.apply(lambda x: append_num(x['happen'],x['valid']), axis=1)
```

and also this loop take forever.

My expected output is something like this:

```
      happen      valid  number
0 2015-01-01 2015-01-01   120.0
1 2015-01-01 2015-01-02   150.0
2 2015-01-01 2015-01-03   100.0
3 2015-01-02 2015-01-02    90.0
4 2015-01-02 2015-01-03    50.0
5 2015-01-03 2015-01-03     0.0
```

As you can see the first row represents the sum of all rows with `happen` on 2015-01-01 and with a `start_date` and `end_date` that contain the 2015-01-01 in `valid`. The `number` column contains the sum (with 120. = 100. + 20.). On the second row, with `valid` going one day forward, I "lose" element with index 1 and I "gain" element with index 2 (150. = 100. + 50.).

Every help or suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: what does your expected output look like for given example?

Comment: It is not easy for me to show an example of output since  the dataframe is very large (even one row of input data could generate several lines of output)

Comment: Try creating a minimal example. It is will increase your chances of getting an answer. In the present form, it is hard to understand what kind of transformation you need.

Comment: Ok, I'll create a new df from scratch